# How to override the user for ECS task via CLI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I've got a *Task Definition* with [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) which executes a script using a regular user.

I'd like to test the script without changing the *Task Definition* by overriding the default user which script is running by using `--overrides` parameter of [`aws run-task`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) command. For example:

```
$ aws ecs run-task \
    --profile myprofile \
    --cluster foo \
    --task-definition mytask \
    --overrides '{"containerOverrides":[{"user": "root"}]}'
```

It returns:

> Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in overrides.containerOverrides[0]: "user", must be one of: name, command, environment, cpu, memory, memoryReservation.

And when running with *containerDefinitions* key:

```
$ aws ecs run-task \
    --profile myprofile \
    --cluster foo \
    --task-definition mytask \
    --overrides '{"containerDefinitions":[{"user": "root"}]}'
```

I've got this error:

> Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in overrides: "containerDefinitions", must be one of: containerOverrides, taskRoleArn, executionRoleArn

---

I've found the post [how to change the environment variables using `aws ecs run-task`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41373167/55075), but it's not clear how to change the user. Help page isn't clear as well (`aws ecs run-task help`).

---

Here is my task definition:

```
$ aws ecs describe-task-definition --profile myprofile --task-definition mytask
{
    "taskDefinition": {
        "taskDefinitionArn": "...",
        "containerDefinitions": [
            {
                "name": "post_deploy",
                "image": "...dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/..",
                "command": [
                    "bash",
                    "post_deploy.sh"
                ],
                "user": "ubuntu", <!--- I'd like to override this!
            }
        ],
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        ...
    }
}
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain what issue you are trying to solve? `I'd like to test the script without changing the Task Definition`